# Plot timelines of timestamps with different labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some timestamped data from different sources that I'd like to visualize by plotting points on parallel timelines.

[I want something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTJ6d.png)

From data that looks like this:

```
id  | type | timestamp
----------------------
1   | A    | 2022-03-11 09:01:00
2   | B    | 2022-03-12 13:13:00
3   | C    | 2022-03-12 20:05:00
4   | B    | 2022-03-12 01:24:00
5   | A    | 2022-03-12 13:03:00
6   | B    | 2022-03-13 11:45:00
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the picture, here is how you can achieve it. I have taken the data in your question above and the graph X-axis has datetime which is spread in equal intervals, while Y-axis has type.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', '2022-03-11 09:01:00'], ['B', '2022-03-12 13:13:00'], ['C', '2022-03-12 20:05:00'],
                   ['B', '2022-03-12 01:24:00'], ['A', '2022-03-12 13:03:00'], ['B', '2022-03-13 11:45:00']], 
                   columns=['type', 'timestamp'])

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(df["timestamp"].values, df["type"].values)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks(np.round(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 3), 2))
```

**Output**

[image: Output Scatter plot]